# Filter data frame based off factor - R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have the following data frame (called `cats`, can be accessed using `library(MASS)`

```
    Sex Bwt  Hwt
1     F 2.0  7.0
2     F 2.0  7.4
3     F 2.0  9.5
4     F 2.1  7.2
5     F 2.1  7.3
6     F 2.1  7.6
7     F 2.1  8.1
8     F 2.1  8.2
9     F 2.1  8.3
10    F 2.1  8.5
```

I first create 3 factors:

```
x = cut(cats$Bwt, breaks=3)
```

Now I need to grab all the data which fits in the first factor, plot it in a boxplot. Then do the same for the other 2 factors.

I have tried:

```
new_data = subset(cats, cats$Bwt %in% x[1])
```

also

```
new_data = cats[which(cats$Bwt == x[1])]
```

I can't seem to filter this data based on the factor. How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that the variable you created is the one you should be iterating over when performing the comparison. So:

```
new_data <- cats[which(x == unique(x)[1]),]
```

Another alternative is not to subset at all but instead use the `facet` functionality from `ggplot` something like this

```
cats %>% 
  mutate(breaks = cut(Bwt, breaks=3)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Sex, y = Hwt)) +
  facet_wrap(~breaks)
```

Comment: Or `boxplot(Bwt ~ x, data=cats)` in base R.